# How to integrate paytm in react native app

Tags: react-native, paytm

I need to integrate paytm in my react native app.
Api written in laravel.
I don't know how to write api to generate transaction token.
Please somebody help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the official docs from the Paytm developer site to integrate the Paytm gateway into the react-native app.

https://developer.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/hybrid-apps/react-native/

Comment: paytm transaction success working fine. But when I clicked back button during transaction  the paytm folder inside vendor disappeared from server .No issues in local .

Comment: I am using expo Is it possible to integrate Paytm in Expo